# New programmer, I need help on greedy.c from Harvard CS50

Tags: c, cs50

I just started programming, so I know this is probably a very basic error, but i've been trying to find out how to fix the logical error in my code for the greedy.c assignment from Harvard's CS50 course without success. I have looked up solutions to the problem, but they all seem to solve it in a different manner than I am trying. I have reverse engineered the other examples, and I understand them now, but I really want to know how to make my own version run well.

I am trying to get the problem done by a series of while loops, each of which subtract a certain coin value from the total owed, and adding one coin to the total coin count.  To me, it seems like logically it makes sense, but when I run the program it doesn't give me the expected output. It just doesn't execute the printf statement at the bottom. I'm hoping one of you wizzes out there can give me a hand with this! Thanks for any help!

Heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("How much change is needed?\n");
    float owed = get_float();
    int coins = 0;
    /*While loops subtracting one coin from change owed, and adding one to coin count*/
    while (owed >= 0.25)
    {
        owed = owed - 0.25;
        coins = coins + 1;
    }
    while (owed >= 0.1)
    {
        owed = owed - 0.1;
        coins = coins + 1;
    }
    while (owed >= 0.05)
    {
        owed = owed - 0.05;
        coins = coins + 1;
    }
    while (owed >= 0.01)
    {
        owed = owed - 0.01;
        coins = coins + 1;
    }
    /*While loops done, now print value of "coins" to screen*/
    if (owed == 0)
    {
        printf("You need %i coins\n", coins);
    }
}
```

Edit:

So I played around with it a little more, and finished that "if" statement. It is returning error for me, so how is the value of "owed" by the end of the program not equal to 0?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("How much change is needed?\n");
    float owed = get_float(); //Gets amount owed from user in "x.xx" format
    int coins = 0; //Sets initial value of the coins paid to 0
    //While loops subtracting one coin from change owed, and adding one to coin count
    while (owed > 0.25)
    {
        owed = owed - 0.25;
        coins = coins + 1;
    }
    while (owed > 0.1)
    {
        owed = owed - 0.1;
        coins = coins + 1;
    }
    while (owed > 0.05)
    {
        owed = owed - 0.05;
        coins = coins + 1;
    }
    while (owed > 0.01)
    {
        owed = owed - 0.01;
        coins = coins + 1;
    }
    //While loops done, now print value of "coins" to screen
    if (owed == 0)
    {
        printf("You need %i coins\n", coins);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
}
```

Edit:

So once my code was working, I started fiddling with it and overengineering. Heres the final(for now) version!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>



int main (void)
{
    srand(time(0));                                             //generates random seed
    float price = round(rand()%500);                            //generates random price between 0 and 500 cents
    printf("You owe %f. How much are you paying?\n", price/100); //shows user their price between 0 and 5 dollars
    printf("Dollars: ");
    float paymnt = get_float()*100;                             //gets the amount user will pay in dollars then converts to cents

    int owed = round (paymnt - price);                         //calculates the change owed by paymnt-price
    int coins = 0;                                              //Sets initial value of the coins paid to 0
    int quarters= 0;
    int dimes = 0;
    int nickels = 0;
    int pennies = 0;

    if (owed ==0 && price >0)                                   //If someone pays in exact
    {
        printf("You paid the exact amount!\n");
    }
    else if (owed < 0)                                          //If someone doesn't pay enough
    {
        printf("You didn't give us enough money!\n");
    }
    else                                                        //Else(We owe them change)
    {
        printf("Your change is %i cents\n", owed);
        //While loops subtracting one coin from change owed, and adding one to coin count
        while (owed >= 25)
        {
            owed = owed - 25;
            quarters = quarters + 1;
        }
        while (owed >= 10)
        {
            owed = owed - 10;
            dimes = dimes + 1;
        }
        while (owed >= 5)
        {
            owed = owed - 5;
            nickels = nickels + 1;
        }
        while (owed >= 1)
        {
            owed = owed - 1;
            pennies = pennies + 1;
        }
        //While loops done, now print each coin and total coins needed to screen
        if (owed == 0)
        {
            coins = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;
            printf("You need %i coins (%i quarters, %i dimes, %i nickels, and %i pennies)\n", coins, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using floating point types for currency accounting is considered a bad idea (and a nice backdoor for rounding frauds).

Comment: For some example input, what is the expected output? And what is the *actual* output? Please edit your question to include those details. And also please take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I changed it to integer calculations. Good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really compare a float point number to a integer ( 0 ) because some of the deep assembly mechanism

What you can do:

1. Simply do `printf("You need %i coins\n", coins)` without condition
2. Do

   ```
   if (owed <= 0.001 && owed >= -0.001)
   {
       printf("You need %i coins\n", coins);
   }
   ```

   It's actually a quite common practice

Comment: Or the OP could follow EugeneSh.'s comment, and implement integer arithmetic and do all the counting in cents.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking something along these lines.  I tried putting this into my code, and I'm still getting error back. I switched the values to if (owed < 0.01 && owed > -0.01)
    {
    printf("You need %i coins\n", coins);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }  and it still isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dr.B, Actually I think all your while loop should be switch to `<=` instead of `<`, your final owed might be a little higher than that

Comment: Yeah it is. Up in the earlier submission it showed the correct way I am entering it with the equals. I switched it for a second just to play with it and forgot to switch it back, but its correct in my post below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. I ended up following Tardis' suggestion, and utilizing integers for the calculations instead.  It was a success!  Heres the code I ended up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("How much change is needed?\n");
    float tmp = get_float() * 100;//Gets amount owed from user in "x.xx" format
    int owed = round(tmp);
    int coins = 0; //Sets initial value of the coins paid to 0
    //While loops subtracting one coin from change owed, and adding one to coin count
    while (owed >= 25)
    {
        owed = owed - 25;
        coins = coins + 1;
    }
    while (owed >= 10)
    {
        owed = owed - 10;
        coins = coins + 1;
    }
    while (owed >= 5)
    {
        owed = owed - 5;
        coins = coins + 1;
    }
    while (owed >= 1)
    {
        owed = owed - 1;
        coins = coins + 1;
    }
    //While loops done, now print value of "coins" to screen
    if (owed == 0)
    {
    printf("You need %i coins\n", coins);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
}
```

Love the feeling of finally getting a program right. Just wish I had been able to come up  with this on my own:/ Nevertheless, thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: Could I have written it like this?  `float owed = round(get_float() * 100);` and removed the need for the tmp variable?